Issues restarting videos on iOS using video_player in Flutter
I'm experiencing an issue when trying to restart videos on iOS using the video_player plugin (version 2.9.2). After the video completes, attempting to restart it using _controller.seekTo(Duration.zero) and _controller.play() causes the video to freeze on the last frame and fail to restart.
This behavior occurs in both debug and release modes. On other platforms (Android and Web), the problem does not occur, and the video restarts as expected.
I would like to know if this is a known issue with the video_player plugin or if I am using the controller incorrectly. Below, I provide more details about the code and the observed behavior.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

Initialize the video using VideoPlayerController (either a network or asset video).

Play the video to completion.

After the video ends, attempt to restart it by calling:

_controller.seekTo(Duration.zero)

_controller.play()



Notice that the video freezes on the last frame on iOS.



Expected Result:
The video should restart and play normally from the beginning.

Actual Result:
The video freezes on the last frame and does not restart. This issue only occurs on iOS. On Android and Web, the behavior works as expected.
Code:
Here is the snippet of code used in the PlayVideo event handler inside the Bloc:
Future<void> _playHandler(PlayVideo event, Emitter<VideoPlayerState> emit) async {
  try {
    if (_controller != null) {
      Logger.instance.i(logKey, '[play] called.');
      
      // Restart the video if it has completed
      if (_controller!.value.isCompleted) {
        Logger.instance.i(logKey, 'Video is completed. Restarting...');
        await _controller!.seekTo(Duration.zero); // Reset video to start position
        Logger.instance.i(logKey, 'Video reset to start position.');
      }

      // Play the video
      await _controller!.play();
      Logger.instance.i(logKey, '[play] sent to platform.');
    } else {
      Logger.instance.w(logKey, 'Controller is not ready.');
    }
  } catch (e, s) {
    Logger.instance.e(logKey, 'Failed to play video.', error: e, stackTrace: s);
  }
}


Additional Information:

Flutter Version: 3.24.3

video_player Plugin: version 2.9.2
Questions:

Is this behavior expected on iOS with the video_player plugin?

Am I using the controller correctly to restart the video?

Are there any known solutions or workarounds for this issue?





Instead of restarting the video, why don't you reinitialize it instead, but the action remains the same (i.e., using a replay button or what). Without asking of how the user interacts with the video UI, I hope my suggestions reflects with your use case, since you mentioned about restarting the video.
